# Find fibonacci series upto a given maximum in javascript

Tags: javascript, fibonacci-sequence

I'm attempting to find a fibonacci series where the last number is no greater than a given maximum. Given the start digits `1`, `2`

Here's my working code.

```
var fib = [1,2];
var max = 4000000;
var i = 2;
var loop = true

while (loop) {
    if (fib[i-1] + fib[i-2] > max) {
        loop = false;
    } else {
        fib.push(fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]);
        i++;
    }
}

console.log(fib)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your loop can be terminated in a few different ways. You're using a boolean `loop` variable, but there are cleaner ways.

One is to simply move the `if` condition to the `while` condition (Malachi's answer beat me to this):

```
while (fib[i-1] + fib[i-2] <= max) {
  i = fib.push(fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]);
}
```

`push` helpfully returns the array's new length, so you don't need the `i++`.

Another is to keep the `if` branching, but use it to `break` the loop instead:

```
while (true) {
  var next = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
  if (next > max) {
    break; // exit the loop
  }
  i = fib.push(next);
}
```

Here we avoid calculating the new fibonacci number twice, but still: the previous code block is probably still the cleanest.

You also initialize `i` to 2, which is a bit redundant: It's the length of the `fib` array. Rather than manually initializing the array, *and* manually recording its length, I'd just do `var i = fib.length`.

Lastly, it might be good to consider "bad" max values. I.e. what if the maximum is set to zero? Or 1? Or -2324359? For zero you could return an empty array; for 1 you'd need to return a shorter array than what you start with, and for the negative max you could throw an error or return null. Not saying you need to any of this, but it's always to good to consider how you handle such cases.

Comment: `push` returns new length - well that's handy thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can remove the `loop` variable by moving that equation into the while conditional statement, like this:

```
var fib = [1,2];
var max = 4000000;
var i = 2;

while (fib[i-1] + fib[i-2] <= max) {
    fib.push(fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]);
    i++;
}

console.log(fib)
```

I just inverted the condition.

Comment: Upvote for the loop simplification, but the other answer use `i = push()` which I liked and had a slightly clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of providing an alternate from the `while` loops already given:

```
var f = (a, b, c, m) => (b + c >= m) ? a : f(a.concat([b + c]), c, b + c, m);
var fib = f([1, 1], 1, 1, 10);
```

Less pretty version for golfs sake (43 chars)

```
a=[];for(b=c=1;c<=10&&a.push(b,c);c+=b+=c)a
```

Comment: Woops, thought this was the CodeGolf SE :)

Comment: I like it, but I think the while loop is a little more readable for me at the minute.